# How to put bootstrap panels next to eachoter

Tags: html

I've been trying this for a while now. I'm a semi beginner to it.

This is what it looks like http://prntscr.com/ceex21

I'm still learning a lot.

And heard this is the place to ask anything regarding

Programming and web design!

This is the code:

```
  <div class="col-xlg-4 col-md-6 hidden-xs">
        <!-- Example Panel With Footer -->
        <div class="panel panel-bordered">
          <div class="panel-body">
            <h4>Body Heading</h4>
            <p>Wrap buttons or secondary text in <code>.panel-footer</code>. Note
              that panel footers do not inherit colors and borders when using
              contextual variations as they are not meant to be in the foreground.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Example Panel With Footer -->
      </div>
      <!-- End Example Panel With Footer -->
    </div>

      <div class="page-content container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xlg-6 col-md-6">
        <!-- Example Panel With Heading -->
        <div class="panel panel-bordered">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Panel Heading</h3>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="example-wrap">
             <h4 class="example-title">Basic</h4>
             <p>Add class <code>.table</code>.</p>
             <div class="example table-responsive">
               <table class="table">
                 <thead>
                   <tr>
                     <th>#</th>
                     <th>First Name</th>
                     <th>Last Name</th>
                     <th>Username</th>
                     <th>Role</th>
                   </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                   <tr>
                     <td>1</td>
                     <td>Teagan</td>
                     <td>Prohaska</td>
                     <td>@Elijah</td>
                     <td>
                       <span class="label label-danger">admin</span>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td>2</td>
                     <td>Andy</td>
                     <td>Gaylord</td>
                     <td>@Ramiro</td>
                     <td>
                       <span class="label label-info">member</span>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td>3</td>
                     <td>Veronica</td>
                     <td>Gusikowski</td>
                     <td>@Maxime</td>
                     <td>
                       <span class="label label-warning">developer</span>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td>4</td>
                     <td>Bruce</td>
                     <td>Rogahn</td>
                     <td>@Maggio</td>
                     <td>
                       <span class="label label-success">supporter</span>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td>5</td>
                     <td>Carolina</td>
                     <td>Hickle</td>
                     <td>@Hammes</td>
                     <td>
                       <span class="label label-info">member</span>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                     <td>6</td>
                     <td>Madaline</td>
                     <td>Eichmann</td>
                     <td>@Amaya</td>
                     <td>
                       <span class="label label-success">supporter</span>
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                 </tbody>
               </table>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Example Panel With Heading -->
      </div>
```

Comment: Hi Bas, just for the record, `col-xlg-4` isn't a valid bootstrap column, you mean either `col-xs-4` or `col-lg-4`

Comment: Just tried it. But still does not seem to put the panels side to side!

Comment: It wasn't ment as an answer, just general feedback, i'm toying around with your code now

Comment: I've recreated your scenario, but can't really understand what you're trying to achieve, can you specify your question?

Comment: What i'm trying to achieve is the panels to be aside of eachoter. And not under eachoter. I like everything organised. Would this be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that should do it...
Just create a row with 2 columns and put whatever you want in your columns.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-bordered">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4>Body Heading</h4>
                <p>Wrap buttons or secondary text in <code>.panel-footer</code>. Note
                    that panel footers do not inherit colors and borders when using
                    contextual variations as they are not meant to be in the foreground.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Example Panel With Footer -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="panel panel-bordered">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h4>Body Heading</h4>
                <p>Wrap buttons or secondary text in <code>.panel-footer</code>. Note
                    that panel footers do not inherit colors and borders when using
                    contextual variations as they are not meant to be in the foreground.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-footer">Panel Footer</div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Example Panel With Footer -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, if you could just "accept" my answer, it would be much appreciated ;)